# Rename the specific files in folder: Changing only first numbers

Tags: powershell, rename

In folder I have different types of files. I need to change the numering of specific type offiles.
Some of them looks like: 01 sasasasa ; 02 dadadad etc.
I need to add 5 to this first two digits. EX: 06 sasasasa ; 07 dadadad...
But
In other folder items for rename looks like 1 bububu ; 2 mumumu etc.
Need to add 5 and add one more 0 in first digit. EX: 06 bububu ; 07 mumumu... When I hit 10+ numering it cannot be: 010.

Tried this easy way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\bongbong -Filter *.txt |
%{
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '01','06' } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '02','07' } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '03','08' } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '04','09' } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '05','10' }
}
```

It is not working on the first example. Cannot find something like -if in powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a more dynamic approach:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\bongbong' -Filter '*.txt' -File) | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^(\d{1,2})(.*)' } |
    Rename-Item -NewName {'{0:D2}{1}' -f ([int]$Matches[1] + 5), $Matches[2]}
```

Comment: It's working with numering for 1 ; 2 ; 3 etc. When I am running this on 01 ; 02 ; 03 everything is ok but 01 goes to 11. However, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

other solution :

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\bongbong" -file -Filter "*.txt" | where Name -match "\d{1,2} ." | %{
#split by space
$Array=$_.ToString().Split(' ')

#take number and add 5
$Number=[int]$Array[0] + 5

#take part of name without number
$PartRight=$Array[1..$Array.Count] -join ' '

#build new name
$NewName="0{0} {1}" -f $Number, $PartRight

#rename file
Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
}
```